# Should I use the field of view or camera's z position for zooming in/out?

Tags: three.js, perspectivecamera

I have a large 2D plane of circles which I've been zooming in and out of (well TrackballControls has) using the camera's Z position (a PerspectiveCamera).

I recently added camera.fov to my DAT GUI controls to play around with it and found that I can fully zoom in and out of my scene using the range 0 to 180 for the field of view.

Which method should I use and why?

Edited:

There are multiple ways to make an object seem closer and further away from the camera:

- moving the object's position (too many objects, so not using this
  one)
- moving the camera's position
- changing the camera's fov property
- changing the camera's zoom property

To be able to smoothly scroll, using the mouse wheel, in and out of of a scene that contains large geometries (millions of vertices), is there a reason why I shouldn't or should use one of the methods above over the others?

Comment: You can also use `camera.zoom( 2 ); camera.updateProjectionMatrix();`  Your question, unfortunately, is an opinion-based one.

Comment: Changing zoom seems to change the fov - https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.js#L95

Comment: All roads are pointing to changing the fov value, but this doesn't play well with TrackballControls. Once you've zoomed in far enough and then try to pan around, the movements don't take into account how close you are now, and so the panning acts like your much further out

Comment: Of course, because you are as far away as before, your position did not change, only the camera's projection. (Same as in real life when you zoom in on sth. and you must be very careful or use a tripod to not get blurred pictures) I guess you could adjust for this circumstance by modifying the controls and using a factor to slow down panning etc. according to zoom distance. 
Anyway, you are answering your own question because changing FoV seems not to be what you want to do,  so you can either move the camera or go for the FoV and adjust controls to compensate for the projection.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you change the cameras position you are not zooming at all, you are just moving it closer or further away.

Using the Field of View variable, you are zooming but this is usually related to a distortion if you get to the extreme values.

So it depends what you need for your application. If distortion is ok and you really need the feel of "zooming" in, you should be going for the FoV variable of the camera. If you need to avoid distortion and want to zoom in, you should better move along the "camera's lookAt vector". Then you could decide if you move the cameras target as you "zoom"  or if you are slowing down the cameras movement if it gets closer to its target, a.k.a focus point. Just use what is suited for your use case.

Maybe some interesting stuff:

http://blog.tartiflop.com/2008/08/understanding-zoom-focus-and-field-of-view-in-papervision3d/

Comment: Actually your first two statements are wrong. If you move the cameras' position, you are in effect zooming in/out. And if you change the Field of View of the camera you are not zooming but changing the perspective projection. Think of it as standing stationary and putting on different type of lenses. Thats why you have distortion.

Comment: Can you explain how to achieve zooming using camera lookat?

Comment: The tricky part is attaching the concept to DAT.GUI so that it all makes sense. Controlling a 3D vector with 2D controls is not very intuitive. Also I would use camera position for zooming, not the lookat. Play with the lookat vector here: http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/991/. It is not for zooming.

Comment: @gaitat: I am really not sure myself but for me, the definition of zooming FOR ME is like this: 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_zoom

Inshort: Changing the field of view, thus changing the perspective projection and getting distortion and thus, as you said, is standing stationary and putting on different types of lenses.  

The other thing is translating the camera object (moving the camera), not zooming. At least this is my definition.  

According to this definition your answer is wrong because you are explaining camera translation / movement, not zooming.

Comment: Ok, you guys seem to be issuing over my use of the word "zooming". I'll edit my question.

Comment: Yes but the effect you want to achieve is to have an object in your viewport appear smaller or larger without distortion. If so, I have already offered my input.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by there being distortion at an extreme zoom level?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to zoom in/out. Either you move the camera closer/further to the object or you move the object closer/further to the camera. Which one you chose only depends on what else you want to do. So if you are in a city and you want to look closer to a car, well you are not going to move the city. 
But if you are examining things (different models) then it might be better to move the camera. (Maybe not very good example).

Comment: Yes I'm not going to move my world around just to zoom. That's why we're allowed to reposition the camera I imagine. I don't want distortion either.

Comment: Also, your answer does nothing to help dps27a, because he wants to know WHICH method he should use. And virtually translating all the objects instead of the camera is not a solution speaking in three.js terms. So why propose this at all. You either move the camera or use field of view, depending on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

- moving the camera's position = best option as it's more compatible
  with interaction
- changing the camera's fov property = best option if
  you want to "zoom" in the true sense of the word, though doesn't play
  well with TrackballControls
- changing the camera's zoom property =
  actually affects the fov value